# Is there a way to place a single edge in the same way you place an edge loop?

Tags: interface, workflow, edges, shortcut

I want to be able to press a shortcut, then hover over an edge, click it and then place a single edge (not an edge loop) just the same way I press Ctrl+R to place an edge loop. Also would be great if I can use the mousewheel to control how many subdivisions or edges to place like you can do with Ctrl+R. Or any way to control how many edges get placed at once.

Is there such functionality? I dont want to use the knife tool which takes so much longer to use because of the extra clicks and the inability to place multiple edges at once. I was trying to get the subdivide tool to do taht but it seems like it doesnt let me subdivide by just hovering over an edge nor can I select how many subdivisions... unless I missed something?

Any other suggestions or workarounds on doing this?

Comment: I don't think theres a clean way to do this. One workaround would be to use the rip feature to separate it from the rest of the mesh, add the edge loops, then use a merge by distance to join it back afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add new edges using the *Subdivide* function.

1. Select two opposite edges
2. Go *Edge > Subdivide*
3. Adjust the number of cuts in the pop-up menu.

[image]

Comment: thanks, this gets it done although do you know if there's a way to be able to place the edge without having to select 2 edges beforehand? Like how with the edge loop tool you can just click on a single edge to place it?

Comment: Hey :). Not to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great to have this tool, as well as creating a single vertex, but I don't think it exists yet. The closest thing I can think of is <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, but it creates other edges:

- Select an edge. Put your cursor on the side of the edge where you want the new edge to be created. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.
- Press <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to make the edge slide.

Comment: thank you, however, what I want to place is an edge, not a vertex. Like for example, I want to be able to hover over one of the edges in your image above to be able to place an edge that is perpendicular to it (like with the edge loop tool) except that I dont want the edge to loop around the entire mesh. I want an edge for just one face.

Comment: yes my bad, I've edited my answer but it's still not what you want, knife tool is the only other thing I see